# How do I nest two field in my node.tpl.php?

Tags: entities, theming

I have two fields of multiple values. When I print render($content['field_photo']) and render($content['field_photo_caption']) I get:

```
<img>
<img>
<img>
<p>caption</p>
<p>caption</p>
<p>caption</p>
```

How do I nest the values to get:

```
<img>
<p>caption</p>
<img>
<p>caption</p>
<img>
<p>caption</p>
```

Comment: Ideally you should use field collections module to group fields together... https://drupal.org/project/field_collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to solve problem

```
  $image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_text_multiple');
  $text = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_multiple_second');
  foreach ($text as $key => $value) {
    $second_field[] = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_multiple_second', $text[$key]);
  }
  foreach ($image as $key => $value) {
    $output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_text_multiple', $image[$key]);
    print render($output);
    print "<br>";
    print render($second_field[$key]);
    print "<br>";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Anil. This solutions works great! But it seems like a lot of logic in the node.tpl.php, which really should just render a variable. Can I use field_get_items() and field_view_value() in a preprocess function?

Comment: of course you can.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make a custom field formatter.

Find the field formatter that sets up the image to be rendered the way you want (look in [image.field.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/7)).  Clone it into your own module.  You will need the info, view, and theme functions.

Then in your clone, you can grab the node from `$entity`.  In the loop that builds up the images, you can get the field with the paragraphs, and stick them into the render tree.

Then, on your **Manage Display** for your content type, select your new formatter.

I normally make my field formatters pretty specific, but you can add options to let you select what field you want to pull in extra info from.